# JSP Servlet Mapping not working

Tags: java, jsp

I want to redirect a JSP file with servlet-mapping so it can be accessed without .jsp extesnsion. I have tried some tutorials but it didn't work.

First, I created a web.xml file under WebContent/WEB-INF directory

This is the content of web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>asukon.jsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/asukon.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>asukon.jsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/asukon</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The file, asukon.jsp is located under WebContent directory

[image: screeshot]

I use Eclipse EE and Tomcat 7
Why it didn't work?

Comment: How is it not working? Do you have any error? What is your form?

Comment: It would be useful if you supplied the URL that didn't work so that future users can see how the answer fixed your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

servlet mapping is working perfectly.My guess is that you are not hitting the proper url.If you will hit `http://localhost:8080/bbb/asukon` ,you will be good.(Assuming `bbb` is your project name as seen in image)

This is what i tried

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form name=login method="post" action="asukon">
    <table>
    <tr><td>UserName</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="userName"/></td>
    <tr><td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><button type="submit">login</button></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet-name>asukon.jsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/asukon.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>asukon.jsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/asukon</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**asukon.jsp**

```
<body>
This is a test page
</body>
```

**Note** -

- When I click on submit button,it is redirecting me to `asukon.jsp`
  with url `http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/asukon`.
- I have kept my HTML and JSP files inside `/WebContent` folder.

Answer (score -1):

You can define servlet-class parameter in servlet tag declaration in web.xml and create servlet class. Your servlet class redirected to your jsp page.
Servlet is the controller in MVC pattern and Jsp is view component.